# How to compare string to a wild card string in shell script?

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, ksh

I want to compare file name string with file mask in a `ksh` shell script. Can you please correct the syntax?

```
if [ "NPER20200422TEST.PTN" = "NPER*.PTN" ]
then
    echo "File matched"
else
    echo "File not matched"
fi
```

I want to match my file string with given file mask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure you're using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) or [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) or [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh), then

```
if [[ "NPER20200422TEST.PTN" == NPER*.PTN ]]
```

Use the double bracket conditional, and the special globbing metacharacters must be unquoted.

Answer (score 2):

In Bourne-like shells including `ksh`, that's what the `case` construct is for:

```
case NPER20200422TEST.PTN in
  (NPER*.PTN) echo "File matched";;
  (*) echo "File not matched";;
esac
```

Note that in the Bourne shell (a historical shell that is no longer in use today, though many people keep confusing `sh` with it), you had to omit the `(`s. Either `(*)` or `*)`  are allowed in standard (POSIX) implementations of `sh`.

Answer (score -1):

You can print your statement with an `echo` and pipe it to the `grep`:

```
if echo NPER20200422TEST.PTN | grep -q "NPER.*PTN"
then
  echo "File matched"
else
  echo "File not matched"
fi
```

`grep -q` will not produce an output

Comment: That would also match on `'fooNPERbarPTNbaz'` and fail to match on `$'NPER\n.PTN'` though.